# Sans Serif Font Anatomy

Tags: fonts, typography

I'm designing a brand identity guidelines, I've made a change to the "J" letter in the logo, i'm using Museo Sans Rounded and the "J" has a top line that doesn't match with the isotype. There is a page where that change has to be explained but i don't know the technical name of the J top line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the capitolized J in Museo Sans Rounded, I think you're referring to the **Arm** of that letter.

[image: J letter]

Quote from http://www.typographydeconstructed.com/arm/

> Definition: The arm of a letter is the horizontal stroke on some
>   characters that does not connect to a stroke or stem at one or both
>   ends. The top of the capital T and the horizontal strokes of the F and
>   E are examples of arms. Additionally, the diagonal upward stroke on a
>   K is its arm. Sometimes arm is used interchangeably with bar or
>   crossbar or cross stroke.
>
> Arm is often also used to describe the mostly horizontal top stroke of
>   C, double-storey a, G, and other glyphs, to include the finial,
>   terminal, spur, or other elements of the stroke.
>
> Also Known As: crossbar, cross stroke